# border-radiusのサイズを指定したい

Tags: html, css

navバーの作成をしているのですが、リンクに対してborder-radiusを使用して枠線をつけたいです。
枠線をつけるところまでは行いましたが文字数によるサイズ・幅の違いをそろえたいです。
この場合、枠線のみに対して別にheightを指定することは可能なのでしょうか。
解決方法のご回答よろしくお願いします。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>madeforyou2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="madeforyou2.css">
</head>    
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="headerlogo"><h1>Made For You</h1></div>
    </div>
    <nav>
       <ul class="navbar">
          <div class="border"><a href="#"><li class="topic">Home</li></a></div>
          <a href="#"><li class="topic">About Us</li></a>
          <a href="#"><li class="topic">Products</li></a>
          <a href="#"><li class="topic">Order</li></a>
          <a href="#"><li class="topic">Contact</li></a>
       </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/*---------------------top image-------------------*強調斜体テキスト*--------*/
h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/4021952/pexels-photo-4021952.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500);
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.headerlogo {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 150px;
}
/*-----------------------------top imgage-----------------------------*/

/*-----------------------------nav bar--------------------------------*/
.navbar {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(233, 133, 20), rgba(230, 134, 24, 0.692));
}
.topic {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 2px rgba(65, 55, 55, 0.452);
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 70px;
  margin-left: 170px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.topic:hover {
  color: rgb(236, 37, 70);
  border: solid 2px rgb(236, 37, 70);
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

シンプルに
枠線をつけているli.topicに対して
widthとheightを指定してあげればいいと思います。

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/*---------------------top image-------------------*強調斜体テキスト*--------*/
h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/4021952/pexels-photo-4021952.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500);
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.headerlogo {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 150px;
}
/*-----------------------------top imgage-----------------------------*/

/*-----------------------------nav bar--------------------------------*/
.navbar {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(233, 133, 20), rgba(230, 134, 24, 0.692));
}
.topic {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 2px rgba(65, 55, 55, 0.452);
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 70px;
  margin-left: 170px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 65px;
}
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.topic:hover {
  color: rgb(236, 37, 70);
  border: solid 2px rgb(236, 37, 70);
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
        <div class="headerlogo"><h1>Made For You</h1></div>
    </div>
    <nav>
       <ul class="navbar">
          <div class="border"><a href="#"><li class="topic">Home</li></a></div>
          <a href="#"><li class="topic">About Us</li></a>
          <a href="#"><li class="topic">Products</li></a>
          <a href="#"><li class="topic">Order</li></a>
          <a href="#"><li class="topic">Contact</li></a>
       </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: 無事できました。ありがとうございました！